# Year query returns no results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Holiday` model, with a `holiday_date` attribute of `DateTime`.
I added a new Holiday (New Years Day) with a date of `1/1/2019`.
When I do in the console `Holiday.last`, I see this:

```
#<Holiday id: 50, name: "New Years Day", holiday_date: "2018-12-31 23:00:00", created_at: "2018-11-13 13:15:54", updated_at: "2018-11-13 13:15:54">
```

So it is saved in UTC time, a day earlier. When I then do `Holiday.last.holiday_date` I get this:

```
Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 CET +01:00
```

Great, the date is converted to our CET date and time. But when I query for a year like this:

```
Holiday.where("extract(year from holiday_date) = '2019'")
```

It returns no results. So it seems that there is no conversion to CET time with this query. How can I make sure that the query returns the holiday I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to cast timezones twice:

```
Holiday.where(
  "extract(year from holiday_date AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'CET') = '2019'"
)
```

This will work, but it would be nice to use indices for your query, we'll just have to prepare it better:

```
year = Time.zone.parse("2019-01-01")
Holiday.where("holiday_date BETWEEN ? AND ?", year.beginning_of_year, year.end_of_year)
# SELECT "holidays".* FROM "holidays" WHERE (holiday_date BETWEEN '2018-12-31 23:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 22:59:59.999999')
```

I would really think whether you need datetimes for your `holiday_date` column, perhaps dates would be enough, so that you don't have to deal with timezones.

Comment: Thanks! Your last remark is correct, it should have been a date.

Answer (score 1):

You can query by timezone like this

```
Holiday.where("extract(year from holiday_date AT TIME ZONE 'CET') = '2019'")
```